# Gravar dados de classe em arquivo .dat, e a cada uso checar se a informação existe

Tags: c, c++, arquivo

Boa noite, pessoal.
Estou escrevendo um código pra um projeto da universidade. Entretanto estou tendo problemas para manipular o arquivo no C++.  Criei uma classe chamada stok   e a quantidade de objetos à serem criados são definidos pelo usuário através de um >> cin. Seus membros são:
**Symbol, amount, open_p, close_p, buy_p;`** e significam:

**Código da ação;  Quantidade; Preço Abertura; Preço Fechamento; Preço de Compra.**

Meu objetivo é ler estes dados do  arquivo .dat para criar algumas outras funções no programa.
Gostaria de saber como eu poderia manipular as linhas do arquivo, por exemplo,  digamos que o arquivo tenha 100 linhas,  como eu poderia acessar os dois últimos objetos salvos no arquivo e manipular o preço de abertura destes?   Digamos que eu queira realizar uma comparação entre o "open_p"  dos dois últimos objetos salvos no arquivo. Como eu poderia fazer? (Acessar a informação no arquivo, armazenar este valor numa variável para posteriormente manipulá-la no main.
Desde já, muito obrigado e me desculpem a falta de experiência, sou iniciante em C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include "stock.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

/* Written by Guilherme;  SENG1200  Final Project 
     Economic  Factor  -  Stocks Alarm System */ 
int main() 
{
    
    int stock_hold;
    string Symbol;
    int amount;
    double open_p;
    double close_p;
    double buy_p;
    
    ofstream stocks("Stockinfo.dat");   //data file created for recording
    

                 // first change of the second solution (user sets the value of stock_hold
                 cout << "Number of shares: ";
                 cin >> stock_hold;
                 //  defines the number of instances. 
  stock* stok[stock_hold];

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(stok)/sizeof(*stok); i++)
    {
        
         
        cout << "\n";
        stok[i] = new stock(Symbol, amount, open_p, close_p, buy_p);
        stocks << stok[i]->getSymbol();
        stocks << stok[i]->getVolume();
        stocks << stok[i]->getOpenP();
        stocks << stok[i]->getCloseP();
        stocks << stok[i]->getBuyP();       
    }
    stocks.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Em geral não é preciso nem eficiente usar os dados direto do disco. O que se faz é ler do disco o conjunto de ações do cliente e manter na memória. Ao final do programa regrava no disco os dados atualizados.

Se for importante pode manter um *journal* do que está acontecendo, um registro analítico das operações, e ir gravando em disco a cada operação. Assim se o programa aborta ou algo sai errado se pode ler esse arquivo e partir do arquivo original e ir refazendo as transações para voltar ao estado do momento do crash.
Se o programa termina normalmente então você apaga o tal histórico e a vida segue.

Como manter na memória? C++ tem várias estruturas convenientes e flexíveis para isso. Talvez possa considerar para as ações um mapa, que é como um dicionário indexado pelos símbolos das ações. Fica "bonitinho" e é fácil. Pode usar uma lista, um vetor, um conjunto, coisas assim.

#### uma classe simples de ação

```
class Stock
{
    string  Symbol;
    int     amount;
    double  open_p;
    double  close_p;
    double  buy_p;

    Stock(string, int, double, double, double);

};
```

Tem o mínimo.

#### uma classe Property

```
#pragma once
#include "Stock.h"
#include <map>

class Property
{
public:
    map<string, Stock>   my_stocks;

public:
    Property(string);
    Property() : Property("default.dat"){};

    int load_from_disk(string);
    int unload_to_disk(string);

};
```

É só um brinquedo, para dar uma idéia: um cadastro de ações.

#### um exemplo criando transações

Imagine uma função que gerasse uma compra de valores aleatórios a partir de um grupo de ações, só pra ter algum dado pra ir testando o programa, algo como

```
pair<string, Stock>      stock_factory(int value)
{
    const string umas[] =
    {
        "LHDX",        "IRTC",        "PLBY",        "CAN",
        "TLSA",        "VECT",        "TSHA",        "AMD",
        "APPL",        "NVDA",        "AMZN",        "MSFT"
    };
    static int init = 999;
    if (value == 0) srand(210412); // reset rand()
    string symbol = umas[rand() % 12];
    Stock  stock(
        symbol,
        ++init,
        1. + rand() % 100 + rand() % 100 / 100.,
        1. + rand() % 100 + rand() % 100 / 100.,
        1. + rand() % 100 + rand() % 100 / 100.
    );
    pair <string, Stock> novo{ symbol, stock };
    return novo;
}
```

Então a cada vez que chama esse troço --- `stock_factory()` --- ela devolve um par, um símbolo e uma "compra", só pra gerar algum dado pra por no mapa. Tem 12 possíveis ações, a quantia vai ser numerada, os valores são aleatórios.

E aí você quer por isso num mapa onde as ações estão carregadas pelo símbolo e cada par tem o registro correspondente... Como eu disse, o mapa é como um dicionário.

#### usando isso só para ver a mecânica

```
int main(void)
{
    Property my_stocks;
    srand(210412);
    for (auto i = 0; i < 100; i += 1)
    {
        pair<string,Stock> nova = stock_factory(1);
        if (my_stocks.stock.find(nova.first) == my_stocks.stock.end())
        {
            cout << "Nova: " << nova.second.symbol << endl;
            my_stocks.stock.insert(stock_factory(1));
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Compra: " << nova.second.symbol << 
                " + " << nova.second.amount << endl;
            my_stocks.stock[nova.first].amount += nova.second.amount;
        }
    }
    cout << "\n" << my_stocks.stock.size() << " Acoes na lista\n";

    for (auto uma : my_stocks.stock)
    {
        cout << 
            setw(4) << uma.first << ": " << 
            setw(6) << uma.second.amount <<
            " $" << uma.second.buy_p << "\n";
    }
}
```

Esse programa cria `my_stocks`, uma carteira.

E faz 100 transações usando a função `stock_factory()`. Se vier uma ação nova põe no mapa. Se já tiver lá soma o `amount`.

Depois mostra como ficou `my_stocks`.

Não serve para nada, escrevi só pra você ver uma possibilidade e pensar no caso. Eis o que o programa mostra:

```
Nova: AMD
Compra: TSHA + 1002
Nova: APPL
Nova: TLSA
Compra: IRTC + 1007
Nova: MSFT
Compra: LHDX + 1010
Nova: MSFT
Compra: IRTC + 1013
Compra: TSHA + 1014
Compra: LHDX + 1015
Nova: CAN
Compra: AMD + 1018
Nova: TLSA
Compra: PLBY + 1021
Compra: LHDX + 1022
Compra: AMD + 1023
Nova: MSFT
Compra: AMD + 1026
Nova: AMZN
Compra: PLBY + 1029
Compra: CAN + 1030
Compra: IRTC + 1031
Compra: IRTC + 1032
Nova: MSFT
Nova: MSFT
Compra: CAN + 1037
Compra: TLSA + 1038
Compra: PLBY + 1039
Compra: PLBY + 1040
Compra: TSHA + 1041
Nova: VECT
Compra: IRTC + 1044
Compra: APPL + 1045
Compra: PLBY + 1046
Compra: CAN + 1047
Compra: TLSA + 1048
Compra: TLSA + 1049
Compra: AMD + 1050
Compra: VECT + 1051
Compra: TSHA + 1052
Compra: VECT + 1053
Compra: PLBY + 1054
Nova: MSFT
Compra: AMD + 1057
Nova: NVDA
Compra: LHDX + 1060
Compra: AMD + 1061
Compra: IRTC + 1062
Compra: IRTC + 1063
Compra: MSFT + 1064
Compra: TSHA + 1065
Nova: NVDA
Compra: TSHA + 1068
Compra: CAN + 1069
Compra: APPL + 1070
Compra: MSFT + 1071
Nova: NVDA
Compra: PLBY + 1074
Compra: IRTC + 1075
Compra: PLBY + 1076
Compra: TSHA + 1077
Compra: VECT + 1078
Compra: AMD + 1079
Compra: APPL + 1080
Compra: LHDX + 1081
Compra: PLBY + 1082
Compra: AMD + 1083
Compra: TLSA + 1084
Compra: TLSA + 1085
Compra: TSHA + 1086
Nova: AMZN
Compra: LHDX + 1089
Compra: LHDX + 1090
Compra: IRTC + 1091
Compra: TLSA + 1092
Compra: LHDX + 1093
Compra: AMD + 1094
Compra: AMD + 1095
Compra: MSFT + 1096
Compra: APPL + 1097
Nova: NVDA
Compra: PLBY + 1100
Compra: APPL + 1101
Nova: NVDA
Compra: AMZN + 1104
Compra: TSHA + 1105
Compra: LHDX + 1106
Compra: MSFT + 1107
Compra: MSFT + 1108
Compra: LHDX + 1109
Compra: MSFT + 1110
Compra: TLSA + 1111
Compra: AMD + 1112
Compra: TSHA + 1113
Compra: APPL + 1114
Compra: LHDX + 1115
Compra: TLSA + 1116
Compra: AMZN + 1117
Compra: AMD + 1118

11 Acoes na lista
 AMD:  13828 $93.6
AMZN:   3324 $4.36
APPL:   7511 $22.79
 CAN:   5200 $38.33
IRTC:  10424 $58.56
LHDX:  12799 $71.03
MSFT:   7612 $2.89
PLBY:  11581 $90.15
TLSA:   9651 $14.07
TSHA:  11624 $89.85
VECT:   4225 $9.34
```

Eis o código: cada classe tem dois arquivos, um com as declarações e outro com o código, e tem o main() que está acima...

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Stock
{
public:
    string  symbol;
    int     amount;
    double  open_p;
    double  close_p;
    double  buy_p;

    Stock();
    Stock(string, int, double, double, double);

};
// fim de stock.h
```

```
#include "Stock.h"

Stock::Stock(string s, int a, double o, double c, double b) :
    symbol(s), amount(a), open_p(o), close_p(c), buy_p(b) {};

Stock::Stock() : symbol("???"), amount(0), open_p(0.), close_p(0.), buy_p(0.){};
// fim de stock.cpp
```

```
#pragma once
#include "Stock.h"
#include <map>

class Property
{
public:
    map<string, Stock>   stock;

public:
    Property(string);
    Property() : Property("default.dat"){};

    int load_from_disk(string);
    int unload_to_disk(string);

};
// fim de Property.h
```

```
#include "Property.h"

Property::Property(string filename) 
{
    //
}

int Property::load_from_disk(string filename)
{
    return 0;
}

int Property::unload_to_disk(string filename)
{
    return 0;
}
// fim de Property.cpp
```

```
#include "Property.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>

pair<string, Stock>      stock_factory(int);

int main(void)
{
    Property my_stocks;
    srand(210412);
    for (auto i = 0; i < 100; i += 1)
    {
        pair<string,Stock> nova = stock_factory(1);
        if (my_stocks.stock.find(nova.first) == my_stocks.stock.end())
        {
            cout << "Nova: " << nova.second.symbol << endl;
            my_stocks.stock.insert(stock_factory(1));
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Compra: " << nova.second.symbol << 
                " + " << nova.second.amount << endl;
            my_stocks.stock[nova.first].amount += nova.second.amount;
        }
    }
    cout << "\n" << my_stocks.stock.size() << " Acoes na lista\n";

    for (auto uma : my_stocks.stock)
    {
        cout << 
            setw(4) << uma.first << ": " << 
            setw(6) << uma.second.amount <<
            " $" << uma.second.buy_p << "\n";
    }
}


pair<string, Stock>      stock_factory(int value)
{
    const string umas[] =
    {
        "LHDX",        "IRTC",        "PLBY",        "CAN",
        "TLSA",        "VECT",        "TSHA",        "AMD",
        "APPL",        "NVDA",        "AMZN",        "MSFT"
    };
    static int init = 999;
    if (value == 0) srand(210412); // reset rand()
    string symbol = umas[rand() % 12];
    Stock  stock(
        symbol,
        ++init,
        1. + rand() % 100 + rand() % 100 / 100.,
        1. + rand() % 100 + rand() % 100 / 100.,
        1. + rand() % 100 + rand() % 100 / 100.
    );
    pair <string, Stock> novo{ symbol, stock };
    return novo;
}
// fim de main.cpp
```

O código de main está acima. Pode juntar tudo em um arquivo só, se quiser experimentar assim. Recomendo deixar separado.

Como já tem dados pode escrever e testar `load_from_disk()` e `unload_to_disk()`, usando mais de uma `Property`...

Se quer mais ou menos dados mude o contador em main(), onde está com 100. E o que deve salvar no disco já estará na sua tela pra testar...

Comment: Perfeito, neto.  Adorei a  alternativa, achei muito inteligente.  
Muito obrigado, vou dar uma estudada no código acima.

Comment: Ao final do programa tem os dados em `my_stocks` no mapa. Então pode chamar `my_stocks.unload_to_disk("dados");` e em seguida declarar `Property outra("dados");` e testar tudo ao mesmo tempo. Se a resposta for útil marque como tal, assim outros podem encontrar mais facilmente respostas que tenham sentido.